# How to protect Vue routes from the wrong user?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good day.

I am working on an application in which every user can create a meeting.
The User and Meeting are in a many-to-many relationship, and that is working correctly.

My question is, how can I prevent User B from accessing User A's meetings.

I will show you my navigation guard and my routes if it helps:

```
    if(to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if(localStorage.getItem('Bearer')){
            next();
        }
        else{ // if not logged in redirects to entry page
            next('/')
        }
    }  // this bit will always redirect you if authenticated
    else if(localStorage.getItem('Bearer') && to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.unAuthenticated)){
        next('/dashboard');
    }
    else next();
})
```

and

````
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Entry,
        meta: {
            unAuthenticated: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            unAuthenticated: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        component: Register,
        meta: {
            unAuthenticated: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/Dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/meeting/:id',
        component: Meeting,
        props: true,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/404',
        component: NotFound
    },
    {
        path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
        redirect: '/404'
    },```
````

Comment: Deciding if a `User` can view a meeting sounds like something that your `API` would determine.

Comment: @Peppermintology should that logic be written in the controller that handles the meetings?

Comment: Correct. Assuming the `User` is authenticated, your controller action would compare that `User` against the `Users` associated with the `Meeting` being requested via the `URL`. If the `User` is not associated then you would return a [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) status.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a full fledged permission libraries like [CASL](https://casl.js.org/v6/en/) for such use cases.

Refer below document:
https://casl.js.org/v6/en/guide/conditions-in-depth#checking-logic-in-casl

Logic based upon document:

You could define User ability with condition that if the meeting access should be based upon the userId

```
const ability = defineAbility((can) => {
  can('access', 'Meeting', { ownerId: { $eq: userId });
});
```

You could implement routing guard with condition to check if meeting's owner is the current user

```
export class Meeting {
  constructor(meetingId, ownerId) {
    this.meetingId = meetingId;
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
  }
}
```

You could add below condition to route guard
ability.can('access', meeting)

If you use such libraries, it will make it quite easy to scale the project further